# Как обойти защиту от парсинга?

Tags: python, парсер, безопасность, beautiful-soup

Этот код должен выводить все, что есть в body. Но похоже у этого сайта какая-то защита от парсинга.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://edadeal.ru/kazan'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
       ' Chrome/86.0.4240.185 YaBrowser/20.11.2.78 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    print(BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'))


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse()
```

В результате, всё, что спарсилось от body, это:

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: пойти и занести админам сайта.

Comment: Все верно у Вас спарсилось, защиты тут нет никакой, сами откройте исходный код страницы https://edadeal.ru/kazan и посмотрите что там. Собственно кроме этого div Вы там в теле ничего и не обнаружите. Что бы парсить такие сайты, нужно понимать как работают сайты, не только статические. Берите fiddler или в режиме разработчика смотрите события сетевые, контент загружается отдельно  на этом сайте, уже после загрузки старинцы. Что бы спарсить, нужно понимать что такое ajax хотя бы, а может там вообще что-то другое. Но суть в том что контент подгружается через js отдельно, и нужно смотреть откуда

Comment: Очень странно, что популярный интернет магазин не сделал ssr. Ибо, то что в блоке только <div id="root'> будет означать, что он очень плохо поисковиками индексируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что данный сайт действительно загружает только `<div id="root"></div>`, такие приложения называются - [SPA (single page application)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Весь остальной контент и DOM дерево создается с помощью JS скриптов.

Чтобы получить полный код страницы после загрузки всех JS скриптов нужно использовать Selenium, а вот после загрузки уже можно передать код страницы на парсинг в BeautifulSoup.

Вот есть [статья](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25) с примером по парсингу динамических сайтов.